# i want to display my data with foreach

Tags: php, json

i am having trouble in displaying my data

```
 $results = curl_exec($sh);
    if (curl_errno($sh)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($sh);
    }
    $count=0;
    $user = json_decode($results);

    foreach($user->$count as $mydata)
{

      echo $mydata->campaignId . "\n";
      count++;

}
```

and this is my data:

```
[limit] => 100
    [offset] => 0
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [actions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => DELETE
                        )

                    [advertiserCost] => 0
                    [ap] => 0.52
                    [approvalStatus] => 
                    [bid] => 
                    [biddingStatus] => ACTIVE
                    [bids] => 0
                    [campaignCountry] => Indonesia
                    [campaignId] => 77c81b87-5476-4efb-be38-a58bfb8cc5b1)
    [1] => Array
                (
                    [actions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => DELETE
                        )

                    [advertiserCost] => 0
                    [ap] => 3
                    [approvalStatus] => 
                    [bid] => 
                    [biddingStatus] => ACTIVE
                    [bids] => 0
                    [campaignCountry] => United States
                    [campaignId] => 1cf85acc-123c-4ef1-8986-05fcd7a7ba93)
```

i want to echo my each campaignid and store it in a variable. i don know the syntax if [0]->campaign id. help please. my data earlier was wrong here is the new data

Comment: `$user->$count`? What is this?

Comment: `foreach($user as $mydata)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the function foreach you dont need a count, like the for function.

```
$results = curl_exec($sh);

if (curl_errno($sh)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($sh);
}

$user = json_decode($results, true);

foreach($user['rows'] as $mydata)
{
      echo $mydata['campaignId'] . "\n<br>";
}
```

Dont forget the second param for json_decode to get an array, not an object.

Comment: hi thanks for the response, i tried running this code but page is still empty when run it.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`
`ini_set('set_time_limit', 0);` 

maybe then you see an error

Comment: check your $user with `echo '<pre>' . print_r($user, TRUE) . '</pre>';` if you got an clean array back or use `var_dump` to check what you got back from this functioncall.

Comment: oh i think i got my data wrong sorry about that. ill edit my post give me a sec

Comment: thats the output of my print_r code or of a other output?

Comment: wow it works, thank you so much ill never forget what i learned from you. i only know basic php